# After writing a location name,can I get my latitude and longitude in android application?

Tags: android, location

Can I write a location name in an edit text and then get it's latitude and longitude using google map in android application??If possible,then give me a way start...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can ..code from fetching long - lat to getting address:

## reverse Geocoding technique

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault());                 
try {
List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
    String _Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```